# PDF metadata to open document in Actual Size (100%) view

Tags: pdf, acrobat, jspdf

I am generating a PDF document using jsPDF. Is there a way to store metadata in the PDF document that will force Acrobat to open it in 100% view mode (Actual Size) vs sized to fit?

In other words does PDF document specification allow that to specify it in the document itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out; in the `Catalog` section of the PDF document, there is a `OpenAction` section where we can specify how the view can show the file, among other things.

I changed this

```
putCatalog = function () {
        out('/Type /Catalog');
        out('/Pages 1 0 R');
        // @TODO: Add zoom and layout modes
        out('/OpenAction [3 0 R /FitH null]');
        out('/PageLayout /OneColumn');
        events.publish('putCatalog');
    },
```

to this

```
    putCatalog = function () {
        out('/Type /Catalog');
        out('/Pages 1 0 R');
        // @TODO: Add zoom and layout modes
        out('/OpenAction [3 0 R 1 100]'); //change from standard code to use zoom to 100 % instead of fit to width
        out('/PageLayout /OneColumn');
        events.publish('putCatalog');
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible, because a PDF document can contain information on how it should open.

You might create such a document in Acrobat and then find the opening information, and/or you might have a look at the Portable Document Format Reference, which is part of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website.

However, I don't know whether you can insert that structure into the PDF with your tool.

Comment: See **8.2.1 Destinations** in Adobe's PDF Reference 1.7. It mentions the **OpenAction** in the document root object may be used to specify a "destination", which in turn may set the zoom level.

Comment: thanks @Jongware your comment did help a bit to move to the right direction.